# Git - How to push single branch to multiple branches

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push

I have three branches `dev` `test` `master`.

Initially i have only dev branch to work with so i used this

`git push origin dev`

BUt later i will have different branches based on env and will deploy from respective branches. Buntill develeopemet is it possible that `test` and `master` always have same  head as dev

or in other words

`git push origin dev|test|master`

so i can push to all branches i single command and later i can merge selective commits. I mean  all other branches are same as dev

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The refspec is:

```
git push remote LocalBranchName:RemoteBranchName
```

You can list as many of these refspecs as you want in a oneline command:

```
git push remote LocalBranchName:FirstRemoteBranchName LocalBranchName:SecondRemoteBranchName LocalBranchName:ThirdRemoteBranchName
```

So if you want to push 3 copies of the `dev` branch to the remote under the different names (`dev`, `test`, & `master`), then:

```
git push origin dev:dev dev:test dev:master
```

Comment: Good answer. Also with bash, you can simplify it to `git push origin dev:{dev,test,master}`.